# Laptop Windows bootloader missing after Kali Linux install

Tags: linux, windows, grub, bootloader

I installed Linux Mint on my Laptop which then installed Grub. With Windows and Linux Mint installed, I could choose which one I want to boot using Grub.
Then I installed Kali Linux, a new Grub and then the Windows Bootloader was gone.

I can still boot in Mint and Kali, but the Windows Bootloader is gone. It is a UEFI system.

This is the output when I type ls ind /boot/efi/EFI:

```
┌──(root㉿kali)-[/boot/efi/EFI]
└─# ls
kali
                                                                                                                                   
┌──(root㉿kali)-[/boot/efi/EFI]
└─#
```

How can I fix this without losing my data?

Comment: First of all, when dual-booting with Windows, disabling its Fast Startup feature is a must. Failing to do so may create several problems with hardware initialization and drives detection. Secondly, you should be able to boot ANY of the OSes directly from UEFI settings > Boot. Knowing that why didn't you try to change the boot order back to Mint? It's a no-brainer.

Comment: Thats the problem. I dont have access to the UEFI settings bc I forgot the password.
I cant reset the UEFI password bc I have a Surface book 2 and no access to the CMOS battery, if there even is one.

Comment: Removing the battery doesn't reset any modern (UEFI) firmware. You shouldn't be installing OSes if you don't have access to the settings, that's just basic. Without the password you're screwed, in a nutshell. You may try contacting Customer Support (with a proof of purchase) but likely they'll tell you the only solution is replacing the motherboard and that will be entirely on you. That said, you may try using `efibootmgr` at least from Mint (it should work from Kali as well but I'm not sure). Finally, Kali is for experts and you definitely aren't one.

Comment: You have WSL with Kali, why you play with things you do not know and understand? Contact Microsoft

Comment: @RomeoNinov Ah, sorry misunderstood.  Thought you were stating OP was using WSL...

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix it by booting on a Windows USB stick and go to the recovery settings. From there I opened the Terminal.

First open diskpart

```
diskpart
```

List disks

```
list disk
```

Select Windows Disk

```
select disk 0
```

List partitions

```
list partition
```

Select System partition

```
select partition 1
```

assign letter v

```
assign letter=v
```

exit diskpart

```
exit
```

Create boot files

```
bcdboot c:\windows /s v: /f UEFI
```